# Linking classes that calculate tax rates in java

Tags: java, mismatch

Getting type mismatch in this line:
`final Map<String, Double> taxRates = new Map<>();` 
Obviously I'm doing something wrong, couldn't figure out what it is.
The code should be able to calculate tax rates for different countries.
Thanks

```
package tax;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class application{

private static Scanner reader;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    //constants
    final Map<String, double> taxRates = new Map<>(); 
    taxRates.put( "China", 0.2 );
    taxRates.put( "Japan", 0.1 );
    taxRates.put( "USA", 0.3 );

    reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables 
    double purchases;  
    double taxespaid;
    double taxRate;   
    String country;

    System.out.print("Enter the country you are purchasing in: ");
    country = reader.nextLine();
    taxRate = taxRates.get( country );
    if( taxRate == null )
    {
        System.out.println( "Could not find country: " + country );
        return; 
    }

    //Request Input 
    System.out.print("Enter your total amount of purchases in " + country + " :"); 
    purchases = reader.nextDouble();

    taxespaid = purchases * taxRate;


    //Display Tax
    System.out.println("The refund amount you owed is $" + taxespaid);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[`java.util.Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is an interface, not a class, and can not be instantiated with `new`.

You will want to pick a concrete implementation of Map, like HashMap.

However, you also can't have maps of primitives, so will need to use the boxed version of double, Double:

```
final Map<String, Double> taxRates = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use primitives in a generic type declaration. You need to use `Map<String, Double>` (capital D) instead. You need to use the concrete class `HashMap` or one of the other implementations of `Map` as well.

As a side note, using `double` will not give you accurate tax calculations. Consider `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Map is an Interface you have to use a Type that is an implementation of the Map Interface (e.g. HashMap).

Bye,
Markus